# Install C# application on user system with system libraries

Tags: c#

I have created a C# 2010 application and now when I install it on user application it asks for complete dot net framework. Is it possible if I can only put required dll files with my application instead of installing complete dot net framework on user machine ?

Comment: Possible, maybe. A good idea, no.

Comment: I think but i'm doing a research that how is that possible ?

Comment: To reduce the .NET framework footprint, choose the **Client Profile** as the target framework for your application.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i do that ?

Comment: That's partially possible for .net3.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No it is not possible

The .NET framework is more than just assembly to copy on the target computer. It is a more complex infrastructure that interact with the OS when an executable is loaded and, if it contains IL instruction, it compile it *just in time* in order to have it running. So non chanches in order to me to have it working without a .NET framework setup, that can be done in a separate step, or by creating a Setup for your app with the proper framework version indicated as a prerequisite.
An [overview of the framework can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw4w595w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), but many more others are available in the net, you should read it to understand why is not a just matter of functions you need or not.

Comment: Yes, but i'm looking for minimal files because my application will not even use all the files given in dot net frame work.

Comment: @fawad install the framework. Any other workaround still a workaround and not supported by Microsoft itself ...

Comment: Well consider the .NET framework as an OS upgrade, you can't really change too much the footprint, the solution could be using the framework Client Profile

Comment: @Felice, I have come to know that GTALK is created using VC++ but you know when you install this app on your system it does not ask for dot net frame work. Why is that so? But i'm sure it comes with all its dll files.

Comment: @fawad Vc++ dos not (necessarily) mean "managed", you can write with VS2xxx a plain old C++ program that does not require the .NET framework

Comment: @Felice, how can I use GUI in C++ then ? I can convert my C# code to C++ but i still need front end interface. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: @fawad, in the tag you are talking about C#, are we talking about c# or C++ ?

Comment: @fawad are you so scared about installing the .NET framework to **rewrite the entire app** ? Trust me, don't, install the framework the disk space occupied I'm sure cost less than your time:)

Comment: My purpose is to get rid of dot net framework my code is written in C#. If anybody can suggest me to build app like Gtalk. I'm more interested in that. Now i'm interested in C++ if it can be used without dot net framework but with GUI.

Comment: @fawad with c# you cna write just managed code, so if you like C# you can't "get rid" of the framework :)

Comment: @fawad of course you can write a GUI in c++, but it is a strong project decision to do it managed or unmanaged so why don't Java etc etc

Comment: Yes. You can write GUI applications in *native* C++ without a dependency on the .NET Framework. However, that's a whole different programming environment. It is non-trivial to port an existing C# application to native C++ code.

Comment: I have some competitor in the market with chat applet. They are giving light weight chat apps without dot net frame work and mine is heavy weight with dot net framework. I'm sure people prefer Gtalk than MSN or yahoo.

Comment: @fawad if it is an exercise go for it, but for marketing, chatting is not exactly a niche market to invest into, but this is just an opinion, of course.

Comment: Your option is very appealing. Thanks for that. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

You may choose to target .NET Framework Client Profile. That would decrease download size of .NET files. See this link for more details on subject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx#targeting_the_net_framework_client_profile

Answer (score 0):

**No, this is not possible.** In order to install and run an application targeting the .NET Framework, the user must have the appropriate version of the .NET Framework installed on his/her computer.

If you want to make things easier, you should distribute your application with a setup program that ensures the .NET Framework is automatically installed along with your app. There's no reason the user should have to download and install the .NET Framework themselves. You can even create a setup program right from Visual Studio, so there's no excuse not to use one. It also makes managing dependencies and versioning conflicts much easier.

If you're really worried about the size of your dependencies and are targeting .NET 4.0, you can require only the [Client Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx), which is a subset of the .NET Framework optimized for client applications. You'll have to set your project's Properties to target the .NET 4.0 Client Profile, and ensure that you're not using any of the assemblies it omits.

I hardly recommend wasting too much time on this, though. At last count, the Client Profile was only about 15–16% smaller than the full version—not an amount that makes much difference on the fast Internet connections found in most parts of the world today. And even less of a problem if you distribute on real media.

---

If you're absolutely dead-set on delivering an application without any dependencies (as comments to other answers suggest), you've got a hard road ahead of you. For starters, you'll need to drop .NET and C# entirely, and switch instead to an unmanaged language like C or C++. That's a *very* different programming environment than C#. Even if you're the best C# programmer in the world, there's going to be a significant learning curve to pick up C++.

And that still doesn't solve all of your problems. C++ applications compiled using a modern version of Visual Studio will still require that the appropriate version of the C Runtime Library be installed on the user's machine. This is, of course, a *much* smaller package than the entire .NET Framework, but you can't count on it always being there, so you'll need to install it along with your application.

Moreover, unlike the .NET Framework (which has WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, etc.) there is no GUI library bundled with C++. And if you choose any GUI library *other* than the native platform API (for example, Qt, which is quite popular for reasons that I still find inexplicable), that gives you an additional dependency. You mention Google's applications a couple of times as a model. Google Chrome targets the Win32 API directly and has written a *bunch* of their own code to draw their custom GUI on top of that base framework. That's really the only way you're going to eliminate dependencies entirely. And delay your app to market for a *significant* period of time.